# Replicate alternative in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an SQL command: `select CONCAT(REPLICATE('*', rank), sname, REPLICATE('*', rank)) from soldiers;`

But it doesn't works, because only mssql supports replicate. How is it possible to manage it in oracle sql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RPAD](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions140.htm) should work

```
select RPAD('*', rank, '*') from soldiers;
```

But this kind of formatting is also easily done client-side (if you have an application between you and the database and are not just using an SQL prompt directly).